# Node promise chain break

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to break out of the promise chain, but even after the `reject('something')` all the `then(methods)` are getting executed and finally the `catch()`. Shouldn't it directly execute the `catch` skipping the `then(methods)`.

```
method1()
.then(method2())
.then(method3())
.then(method4())
.then(method5())
.catch(errohandler())


method1(){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (some condition) {
      reject(new Error("error"));
    } else {
      resolve("correct entity. all parameters present");
    }
  });
}
```

The control goes to the if block as my condition is true and also the error message is getting displayed in catch block later. However all the then(methods) are getting executed.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you call to method2()... and not put mehod2 as function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass the methods as callbacks but you actually call them and pass their results to the promise chain. Change it to this and it should have the expected behaviour.

```
method1()
.then(method2)
.then(method3)
.then(method4)
.then(method5)
.catch(errohandler)
```

---

Update after modified scenario in comments:

If you want to call `method2` with some parameters of the surrounding function then you could do it like so:

```
function myFunc(a, b){
    method1()
        .then(function() { method2(a, b); })
        // ... other chain elements
        .catch(errohandler()) 
}
```

Comment: So this is the complete scenario
myFunc(a,b){
method1()
 .then(method2(a,b))
.then(method3(d,e))
.then(method4(f,g))
.then(method5(h,i))
.catch(errohandler())
}

method1(){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (some condition) {
      reject(new Error("error"));
    } else {
      resolve("correct entity. all parameters present");
    }
  });
}

function method2(a,b){
   console.log(a)
   // do some action
new Promise(resolve,reject){
 // some code  
   resolve(a);
 }
}
Similarly other methods are also written
Can you please explain with this eg

Comment: Yea it is the same issue as in your original question. You still call the methods when 'building' your promise chain. If you want to call method2 with the arguments a & b then you have to pass a callback to the promise which does that. I will edit my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks .. that helped :)