# node.js promise - passing params in a chain?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

`getAccountPromise` returns some ID response.
How exactly do I pass this variable to the next function in the promise chain?

```
var Promise = require('promise');
exports.createCampaign = function createCampaign(tokens, url, fund, insights)
{
    var a = helper.getAccountPromise(tokens);
    a.then(helper.getFundingPromise())
    ....
```

Comment: If it returns the ID then the next function will receive it as an argument

Comment: you mean to leave it empty the second one? tried that.. on the  arg print of the second  function I get "undefined"

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve as I am not familiar with your code. Do you want the result of the promise 'a' to be passed to the call of helper.getFundingPromise()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you call `helper.getFundingPromise` and pass its resulting promise as callback into your promise chain. Just get rid of the parentheses so that you pass the function itself as callback.

```
var Promise = require('promise');
exports.createCampaign = function createCampaign(tokens, url, fund, insights)
{
    var a = helper.getAccountPromise(tokens);
    a.then(helper.getFundingPromise)
    ....
```

Comment: btw - if I want to pass 2 arguments - one from the previous Promise, and second is in the scope - is it like  helper.getFundingPromise(XXXX, myAvailableVar)? how do I exactly "asks" for the previous result

Comment: then you would need to pass a new callback (e.g. anonymous function) which creates a closure with your outer variable. See the following answer from me which describes essentially exactly that with an arguments from an outer function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992107/node-promise-chain-break/37992208#37992208